# Redirect to another URL in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls

I have this default configuration of django admin URL.
I have another unique identifier field in my model.

What I want to achieve is to allow it to redirect:

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/cart/uniq_identifier/change
```

to:

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/cart/cart_id/change
```

A clear example would be:

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/cart/1ASFFX24/change
```

will be redirected to:

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/cart/1/change
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Do you mean that you want people to enter the first URL, and then be redirected to the second? Why?

Comment: i want to use these url patter to sent to my staffs to be processed.